# Colab can't find a file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
training_dataset_file = open('C:/Users/kbg04289/Desktop/mnist_train.csv', 'r')
```

I tried several methods
like 'making address with \' and checking path.

Only google colab makes trouble, however jupyter notebook and visual studio code does well.

Comment: Hi, it seems like you are trying this code inside a colab notebook? If so, it would not have access to files that are located locally in your computer. Maybe you could update your question to better describe your problem?

Comment: sorry! you thought right. and it works well...!  really thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Colab doesn't have access to your local drive.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded_files = files.upload()
```

This will prompt you to upload a file to Colab and you'll then be able to do the following once the upload is complete:

```
training_dataset_file = open(uploaded_files['<filename>'], 'r')
```

Comment: Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people
experiencing a similar issue and will help to get your question noticed. For more
information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily upload files from your local drive to your google collab notebook directory by clicking the folder icon in the navigation panel to the left of your notebook and then dragging any file from your local directory into that navigation panel.

You will see a green check when it is finished and a warning that says "make sure the file is saved somewhere else. This file will be deleted when the notebook session is closed."

[Click the folder icon, then drag your folder in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW5za.png)